# Print values of struct type in gdb using address

Tags: c, struct, gdb

Given an address of a struct type variable let's say : 0x61b2e0 .
I know this address points to a struct of type : s_a, which is defined as

```
typedef struct {

int n;
char *v;

} s_a;
```

How could I print values of this struct filed using the address I know.

thanks,

Comment: `p *((s_a*)(0x61b2e0))`

Answer (score 6):

`(gdb) p *((s_a *)(<address>))` should help you to print a content of the structure referenced by `<address>` virtual address
i.e. in you case it would be:
`(gdb) p *((s_a *)(0x61b2e0))`

Answer (score 0):

To examine memory without dependence on the program's data type gdb provides the x command with follow syntax,

```
x/nfu addr
```

Here the `/nfu` is optional, where

n - how much memory to display in count according to the option u. Negative sign at front will cause the read with decremented address

f - display format

u - unit size. For E.g., 'h' correspond to halfwords

For the given structure, read for two integer sizes according to your machine will give the structure content. The first integer for the value of `n` and second for the pointer address. So here for two word read,

```
x/2uw 0x61b2e0
```

Comment: While this works, using a cast in the print as @meowgoesthedog mentioned is a better answer.

Comment: I agree as well.